# Firebase Data not Showing in ListView on Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[Data Structure Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaA62.png)

[Part of user1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KqHT.png)

I am trying to build my firebase project on android in which i have to view a list of notifications but i am unable to view it in list view.
If i create a local array object it appears in the list.
I checked it though debug option and i could see the data coming into the array.

#### Main:

```
public class Notification extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Notifications";

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mNotificationDatabaseReference;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String userUid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userUid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mNotificationDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("USER").child("User1").child("notifications");

    final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

    // Read from the database
    mNotificationDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Word value = postSnapshot.getValue(Word.class);
                words.add(value);
                // TODO: handle the post
            }// This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.

            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + words);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });


    WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.notification);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

#### Adapter:

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word>{

private static final String LOG_TAG = WordAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * This is our own custom constructor (it doesn't mirror a superclass constructor).
 * The context is used to inflate the layout file, and the list is the data we want
 * to populate into the lists.
 *
 * @param context        The current context. Used to inflate the layout file.
 * @param words A List of words objects to display in a list
 */
public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
    // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
    // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
    // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
    // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
    super(context, 0, words);
}

/**
 * Provides a view for an AdapterView (ListView, GridView, etc.)
 *
 * @param position The position in the list of data that should be displayed in the
 *                 list item view.
 * @param convertView The recycled view to populate.
 * @param parent The parent ViewGroup that is used for inflation.
 * @return The View for the position in the AdapterView.
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
    Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
    TextView notificationHeadView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_head);
    // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
    // set this text on the name TextView
    notificationHeadView.setText(currentWord.getNotificationHead());

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
    TextView notificationDateView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_date);
    // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
    // set this text on the number TextView
    notificationDateView.setText(currentWord.getNotificationDate());

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
    TextView notificationBodyView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_body);
    // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
    // set this text on the number TextView
    notificationBodyView.setText(currentWord.getNotificationBody());

    // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
    // so that it can be shown in the ListView
    return listItemView;
}

}
```

#### Word:

```
public class Word {

private String notificationHead;
private String notificationDate;
private String notificationBody;

public Word(){

}
public Word(String notificationHead, String notificationDate, String notificationBody){
    this.notificationHead = notificationHead;
    this.notificationDate = notificationDate;
    this.notificationBody = notificationBody;
}

public String getNotificationHead(){
    return notificationHead;
}
public void setNotificationHead(String notificationHead) {
    this.notificationHead = notificationHead;
}

public String getNotificationDate(){
    return notificationDate;
}
public void setNotificationDate(String notificationDate) {
    this.notificationDate = notificationDate;
}

public String getNotificationBody() {
    return notificationBody;
}
public void setNotificationBody(String notificationBody) {
    this.notificationBody = notificationBody;
}
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: please post your database structure

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque please check the links for database structure on the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, try this:

1) Move the array declaration out of your onCreate() method, make it a member variable of your activity so you don't have to declare it final:

```
ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
```

2) Add the adapter declaration as a member variable of your class as well and instantiate the adapter **before** you access the database:

```
    adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.notification);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

3) Finally, after you've added all data to the list, call `notifiyDatasetChanged()` no the adapter to refresh the list.

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Word value = postSnapshot.getValue(Word.class);
                words.add(value);
                // TODO: handle the post
            }
 adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks @Levi it worked but every time i update my database. New entries appear with pre-existing data.

Comment: okay, you should either change the listener for a ChildAdded one or clear the data list everytime a new change happens and readd all data again.

Comment: my issue was similar, although I had the local-parameter of a list-adapter, I created another one after the loop and it caused random instability when scrolling.  @LeviMoreira 's answer forced me to give an honest code review.